# systemctl start docker - Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: docker, systemctl

systemctl start docker  - Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See `systemctl status docker.service` and `journalctl -xeu docker.service` for details.

**$ systemctl status docker.service:**

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-03-22 18:28:48 WET; 19min ago
TriggeredBy: × docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 5585 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --host=fd:// --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 5585 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 12.262s

mar 22 18:28:48 fedora systemd[1]: docker.service: Consumed 12.262s CPU time.
mar 22 18:28:48 fedora systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
mar 22 18:28:48 fedora systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
mar 22 18:28:48 fedora systemd[1]: docker.service: Consumed 12.262s CPU time.
mar 22 18:28:48 fedora systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
mar 22 18:28:48 fedora systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mar 22 18:28:48 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

**$ journalctl -xeu docker.service:**

```
The unit docker.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
mar 22 18:28:48 fedora systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
 
 Automatic restarting of the unit docker.service has been scheduled, as the result for
 the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
mar 22 18:28:48 fedora systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
 Subject: A stop job for unit docker.service has finished
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
 
 A stop job for unit docker.service has finished.
 
 The job identifier is 5301 and the job result is done.
mar 22 18:28:48 fedora systemd[1]: docker.service: Consumed 12.262s CPU time.
 Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
 
 The unit docker.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
mar 22 18:28:48 fedora systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
mar 22 18:28:48 fedora systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Subject: Unit failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
 
 The unit docker.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
mar 22 18:28:48 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
 Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel 
A start job for unit docker.service has finished with a failure.
The job identifier is 5301 and the job result is failed.
```

Help, please?

Iḿ trying to start the docker

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the list of files present inside the `/etc/docker/`
If there is file named `daemon.json`

```
sudo rm -f /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

try deleting it and again run

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

You are good to go :)

**NOTE:** If you are trying to create your private docker registry then in that case you need that daemon.json file,
Make sure that you are providing the correct ip and port where your private docker registry is hosted ...
If you are not creating your private docker registry then you can skip this part and run it directly by deleting that `daemon.json` file.

:)